# js - return an array without elements removed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
arr = ["a","b","c"];
```

How could I do in order to remove value "c" and then return array `["a","b"]`?

Comment: See slice() and splice().

Comment: [Mastering JavaScript Arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) is well worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the index of the item being removed with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and you can eliminate the particular element with [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), like this

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
arr.splice(arr.indexOf("c"), 1);
console.log(arr);
# [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

The second parameter passed to `splice` is to instruct how many elements to be removed from the index specified with the first parameter.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist But that removes only the last element. What if `c` is in the middle?

Comment: Then you use a different method. I mention `pop` because it is not clear from the question which is more suited to the OP's use case. If the element to be removed always happens to be last, no need to compute `indexOf`.

Comment: I've just tried your method. And it returned value "c" instead of array ["a","b"].

Comment: @user3247703 I think it was not clear earlier. Please check the update now.

Comment: It still turned out value "c". I already know "splice", which cut off element from array. But it normally returns removed value instead of array. And in this case, I need the inverse values of splice method.

Comment: @user3247703 Please check the answer again, we are ignoring the value returned by `splice` and the `arr` will have the elements without `'c'`

Answer (score 0):

```
return arr.filter(function(e) { return (e !== 'c') ; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find in arr.splice(arr.indexOf("c"));